# Can't complete dropbox installation from behind proxy

Tags: proxy, authentication, dropbox

### Problem:

My PC on campus sits behind a proxy (requiring authentication) and I can't setup Dropbox. I am convinced that this is a proxy issue as I can't setup Ubuntu one either (but I don't use Ubuntu One so that is not a problem). I have looked at the Ubuntu One fix but it seems to be to modify settings explicitly related to Ubuntu One. I can install the nautilus-dropbox package (compiled from source and from .deb package from website and from software centre) but once I click OK from the "Dropbox Installation" dialog box (prompting me to download the proprietary daemon) the installation just freezes with the OK button pressed. When I look at its process in System Monitor its waiting channel is inet_wait_for_connect.

I have set the following proxy directives thus far:

1. Added mj22:**@proxy.waikato.ac.nz:80 information to network proxy settings under
   network in settings.
2. Added http_host and http_port variables under gconf-editor->system->proxy
3. Added 'host', 'authentication_password' 'authentication_user' and ticked 'user authentication' and 'use_http_proxy' under gconf-editor->system->http_proxy
4. Added export http_proxy="http://mj22:**@proxy.waikato.ac.nz:80/" to /etc/bash.bashrc
5. Added Acquire::http::proxy "http://mj22:**@proxy.waikato.ac.nz:80/"; to /etc/apt/apt.conf (which is what I imagine is letting Software Center retrieve packages).

(where ** is my password)

I have also added the equivalent ftp and https lines for the above entries. I get the internet fine and Software Centre can download packages but thats it.

### Related issues:

1. The software centre can't fetch reviews (but can download packages).
2. When trying to add an online account in Gnome 3 a dialog pop up appears with "Error getting a Request Token: Cannot connect to proxy (proxy.waikato.ac.nz)"

---

**Updates:**

After some time (10mins ish) Dropbox shows an error dialog box that reads:

> Trouble connecting to Dropbox servers. Maybe your internet connection
>   is down, or you need to set you http_proxy environment variable.

Is there a way I can see what environment variables are currently set?

Comment: Running `env` in terminal should show you environment variables. Is http_proxy set there? If not you could try adding it with export http_proxy="http://mj22:**@proxy.waikato.ac.nz:80/"

Comment: @kikixx. Yes. env shows both http_proxy=http://mj22:**@proxy.waikato.ac.nz:80/ and ftp_proxy=http://mj22:**@proxy.waikato.ac.nz:80/ are set. Should they appear with quotation marks as shown by env?

Comment: Sorry Mark, it looks like the proxy settings are in a [bit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/795519) [of](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/861443) a [state](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/876839) in 11.10. After "applying system wide" can you check /etc/environment and confirm it is in there also? Last suggestion from me is to add the http_proxy variables to /system/proxy and /system/http_proxy in case it is checking legacy values.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
sudo https_proxy="https://username:password@your_proxy:proxy_port" dropbox start -i
```

You have to run the deamon as root, and thus, you have to configure the proxy as root. Setting the httpS_proxy root env variable on invocation should be enough.

Comment: This didnt work for me... but Ingo Karkat solution did it :)

Comment: As of Feb-2014, `http_proxy` doesn't works, since the binary is expected to be downloaded from a secured web server. So `https_proxy` should be the right variable to use.

Comment: ``sudo`` is not needed

Comment: Finally worked! Thanks also to RajaRaviVarma for the https info.

Comment: Tested it without `sudo` and it works. I would prefer to do it without `sudo` since Dropbox puts the files in `$HOME/.dropbox-dist`, which shall be owned by the current user rather than root.

Answer (score 16):

What is still missing is the installation of the Dropbox daemon. You can download and install it manually; this is documented at https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

32-bit:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

64-bit:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Comment: @IngoKarkat This no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps anyone, I had an issue with the proxy settings and although I had them set they weren't enabled:

You can see if they are enabled like this:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled
```

And enable them if they aren't like this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled true
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone uses proxy that requires authentication:

```
sudo http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:proxy_port dropbox start -i
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`, I had to separately set proxy for Dropbox.

I did that by running following command.

```
sudo dropbox proxy manual http proxyhost proxy_port username passowrd
```

Run `dropbox help proxy` for more information.

If you run into permission issues, follow this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/72) for solution.

Note: I installed Dropbox using [Dropbox APT Repository](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/246).
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.