# dropbox installation failed (behind proxy)

Tags: proxy, dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure proxy authentication to work with Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77449/how-to-configure-proxy-authentication-to-work-with-ubuntu-software-center)

I'm new to Ubuntu (12.10), maybe I'm doing something stupid, but I can't get Dropbox work.

1st try: I tried to install it via the SoftwareCenter, the result is the dropbox symbol in the Launch bar. Klicking on it is effectiveless, it only asks for the password and then stops doing anything.

2nd try: in the terminal with

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

which results in

```
--2013-01-17 17:53:28--  https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64
Resolving proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de (proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de)... 193.196.64.2
Connecting to proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de (proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de)|193.196.64.2|:8888... connected.
Proxy tunneling failed: Proxy Authentication RequiredUnable to establish SSL connection.

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

3rd try: from the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69434/cant-complete-dropbox-installation-from-behind-proxy) I tried the suggested solution:

```
https_proxy=http://proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de:8888 dropbox start -i
```

which results in

```
    Starting Dropbox...
Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? Head to http://www.dropbox.com/
Enter username for Squid proxy-caching web server at proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de:8888: user
Enter password for user in Squid proxy-caching web server at proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de:8888: passwd
Downloading Dropbox... 100%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1404, in <module>
    ret = main(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1393, in main
    result = commands[argv[i]](argv[i+1:])
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 817, in update
    download()
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 556, in download
    name, i, total = one_member.next()
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 278, in unpack
    if not verify_signature(StringIO.StringIO(DROPBOX_PUBLIC_KEY), signature, self.local_file):
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 201, in verify_signature
    sigs = ctx.verify(sig_file, plain_file, None)
gpgme.GpgmeError: (7, 58, u'No data')
The installation of Dropbox failed.
```

I don't know what else I can try :(
Does anyone know what I can do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I already did the configuration by creating a apt.conf file in /etc/apt containing Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:passw@proxy:port/"; - same for https, ftp and socks. Since I did that, the update function worked. I guess that means the system knows the proxy-settings, including the authentication...

Comment: @qbi From a glance, this has nothing to do with the software center.

Comment: There's a bug report for this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-dropbox/+bug/905223